# Internal server communication php

Tags: php, codeigniter, server-communication

I am building an app that will first be a web app and soon will get built into a mobile app.

My approach to this is. Have core app built and deployed on one machine. The web-app will be on a different machine (both on amazon). The web app is just ui wrapper in this situation. It will make all the calls to the core app  to function.

My question here is. What is the best way for the webapp server and core app server to talk to each other?

- Does everyone just use http calls for this purpose?
- Are there any open-source tools/libraries that help here?

Platform : lamp with codeigniter on amazon.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I think http with REST is the approach to take. As far as the SO vigilante down-voting and wanting to close the question, without leaving a comment, I think the only feedback I get from that is, there are some people that don't like questions being asked / answered on SO, very sad.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own **REST** based **API** service and communicate to it from different applications. You can consider **JSON** as request and response data type, as it is most optimized and widely acceptable.

So, the technique is:

- Separate application functions from front-end functions.
- Let the API handle all the application functions.
- Let your front-end system(s) call the application functions through the API.

Answer (score 0):

Create restful web service for this purpose. Use JSON as an output data. This will make it easy to access in all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

REST is my first choice. Since you mentioned that you are using codeigniter, this align with the way Codeigniter works. For the message type you can use json/XML , however since json is JavaScript object, I think you should use json.